# How can convert String to Json Array

Tags: android

I'm getting error cannot convert String to json object ..

While I'm converting this String

```
{"user_id":   "user_id: 140" };
```

Error getting due to the format problem?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: you get the error because you have not a JSONArray but a JSONObject

Comment: can u briefly tell me how can convert..

Comment: I want to get user_id..

Comment: Look at the related questions on the right.

Comment: JSONObject response=new JSONObject(respone);
   
   JSONObject Data=response.getJSONObject("user_id");
   
   int user_id=Data.getInt("user_id");

Comment: Above code is right or wrong??

Comment: {
    "user_id": {
        "user_id": "140"
    }
} with this json your code is good

Answer (score 0):

try this   `JsonObject object=new JsonObject(jsonString);` your string will be converted to JsonObject.

Answer (score 0):

```
{"user_id":   "user_id: 140" };
```

Please make sure that your json string is true.

Example JSON String:

```
[{"property":"value"}, {"property":"value"}, ...]
```

OR

```
{"property":[{"property":"value"}]}
```

OR

```
...
```

So may be your JSON String is not correct.

You can try with (Without ";" at the end of line)

```
{"user_id":"140"}
```

If you assign user_id: 140 as value then:

```
{"user_id":"user_id:140"}
```

Please make sure that at the end of line have no ;

And, how to parse JSON String???

The first {} => Object, [] => Array

- Object without name

  JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
- Object without name but in JSONArray

  JSONObject jObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index); // example: index = 0
- Object with name and in JSONArray

  JSONObject jObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject("name_of_object");
- JSONArray is like JSONObject & jsonArray above is an instance of JSONArray